# Compiling a PHP extension

Tags: c, makefile, php-extension

I have two versions of PHP installed on the system, one in `/opt/local` (API=20090626) and another in `/opt/php54` (API=20100525). I'm trying to compile an extension for the `/opt/php54` version, so I run `/opt/php54/bin/phpize` in the extension directory, then `./configure --enable-<ext> && make && sudo make install`. The problem though is that the compiled extension is not for API=20100525, but rather for API=20090626 (the one in `/opt/local`). Even when running `make install`, it tries to install it in `/opt/local` instead of `/opt/php54`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--with-php-config=/opt/php54/bin/php-config` to the configure string.